# FFmpeg using png with tranparency and exclusion blending mode

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I'm trying to use the exclusion blending mode to blend together a video and a png with transparency. I've looked around quite a bit but I can't find a solution that works for me. Here's the ffmpeg command:

```html
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i text_white_bg_trans.png -filter_complex\
  "[1:v]setsar=sar=1,format=rgba[txt]; [0:v]format=rgba[mo]; [mo][txt]blend=all_mode='exclusion'"  out_exclusion.mkv
```

Edit: and the console output:

```html
ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=xv --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-vda --enable-videotoolbox --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'movie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5143 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1640x1232, SAR 1:1 DAR 205:154, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:11.880000000
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'text_white_bg_trans.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1640x1232, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'out_exclusion.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'out_exclusion.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p, 1640x1232 [SAR 1:1 DAR 205:154], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> setsar
  blend -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   24 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=  frame=   47 fps= 40 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=  frame=   61 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=      96kB time=00:00:00.12 bitrate=6567.3kbitsframe=   70 fps= 32 q=28.0 size=     264kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=4513.9kbitsframe=   83 fps= 30 q=28.0 size=     498kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=4079.5kbitsframe=   95 fps= 29 q=28.0 size=     691kB time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=3827.5kbitsframe=  106 fps= 28 q=28.0 size=     896kB time=00:00:01.92 bitrate=3823.7kbitsframe=  118 fps= 27 q=28.0 size=    1132kB time=00:00:02.40 bitrate=3863.7kbitsframe=  130 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1338kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate=3806.1kbitsframe=  142 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1588kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate=3871.7kbitsframe=  154 fps= 25 q=28.0 size=    1808kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=3856.9kbitsframe=  166 fps= 25 q=28.0 size=    2062kB time=00:00:04.32 bitrate=3910.9kbitsframe=  178 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    2328kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate=3972.8kbitsframe=  190 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    2620kB time=00:00:05.28 bitrate=4064.7kbitsframe=  203 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    2886kB time=00:00:05.80 bitrate=4076.0kbitsframe=  215 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    3132kB time=00:00:06.28 bitrate=4085.9kbitsframe=  226 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    3357kB time=00:00:06.72 bitrate=4092.5kbitsframe=  238 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=    3589kB time=00:00:07.20 bitrate=4083.9kbitsframe=  250 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    3794kB time=00:00:07.68 bitrate=4047.3kbitsframe=  260 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    3978kB time=00:00:08.08 bitrate=4032.7kbitsframe=  272 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    4212kB time=00:00:08.56 bitrate=4031.0kbitsframe=  284 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    4453kB time=00:00:09.04 bitrate=4035.3kbitsframe=  295 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    4632kB time=00:00:09.48 bitrate=4002.9kbitsframe=  297 fps= 20 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5559kB time=00:00:11.80 bitrate=3859.4kbits/s speed=0.808x    
video:5556kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.053747%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.70  size: 56001
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] frame P:178   Avg QP:23.12  size: 24833
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] frame B:117   Avg QP:25.78  size:  9886
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] consecutive B-frames: 29.3% 49.8% 14.1%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] mb I  I16..4:  9.5% 75.0% 15.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] mb P  I16..4:  4.0% 14.8%  1.0%  P16..4: 43.3% 12.0%  4.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:20.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  1.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 48.5%  4.2%  0.3%  direct: 0.6%  skip:43.8%  L0:42.5% L1:55.6% BI: 1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] 8x8 transform intra:74.8% inter:85.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] coded y,u,v intra: 31.3% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 15.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 30% 32% 13% 25%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 22% 32%  3%  4%  3%  6%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 33% 16%  3%  4%  3%  9%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] ref P L0: 72.2% 17.9%  7.5%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] ref B L0: 90.9%  8.6%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] ref B L1: 98.6%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb10a01e200] kb/s:3830.94
```

Edit: Here's a frame from the output. 
[image]
The output video is B&W rather than the original color (not sure why). The rectangle in the image is located where there is a block of text on a png with a transparent background. The png is the same size as the video.

I'm expecting something more like this:
[image]

@Mulvya suggestion fixed the issue with color but I'm still seeing some problems with transparency being handled. I'm attaching a few different images below that each create different problems. All created in Photoshop CC (therein may lie the problem).

A transparent background with a separate text layer that is then exported by Save->png, Photoshop appears to merge these two layers but differently than when "merge layers" is chosen before export. The exported image looks like the B&W image I posted above but with color.

The in the second I merge the layers before exporting. It appears the entire image is treated as white.

In the third I draw "hello" on a transparent layer with a "soft" brush using different grays then export. Transparent areas are rendered as white, gray or translucent areas opaque or with a strange dithering "effect."

It seems I'm moving outside the realm of StackOverflow, but I'm not sure where this post would be better suited.
1
[image: 1]
2
[image: 2]
3
[image: 3]

Comment: Show the console output.

Comment: Execution shows no errors. What doesn't work?

Comment: Added image, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the output from the blend filter is good, but apparently, there's a bug - either in how the blend filter flags the pixel format of its output or in the auto-inserted format conversion that occurs upon the output.

If you insert a scale filter afterwards, the result should be OK.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i text_white_bg_trans.png -filter_complex\
  "[1:v]setsar=1,format=rgba[txt];[0:v]format=rgba[mo];\
   [mo][txt]blend=all_mode='exclusion',scale=0:0"  out_exclusion.mkv
```

You may wish to insert `format=yuv420p` after the scale to produce output that most players will play.

---

If you premultiply the alpha, translucency should be handled correctly.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i text_white_bg_trans.png -filter_complex\
  "[1:v]setsar=1,format=rgba,geq=r='r(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255':g='g(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255':b='b(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255'[txt];\
   [0:v]format=rgba[mo];\
   [mo][txt]blend=all_mode='exclusion',scale=0:0"  out_exclusion.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The change you suggest fixes the color issue but it appears that transparency is being treated as binary. In cases where there are translucent pixels they are being rendered opaque. Still, since I'm able to get the results I want simply by re-exporting the text image with a black background I'll mark your answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: Can you upload the PNG with transparency?

Comment: Thanks for the additional fix, you are a boss.